# Why is ἀτρύγετος = ἀ + τρυγάω + τος "formally not easy?"

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek, homer

Homer uses ἀτρύγετος as an epithet of the sea and sky. The etymology has traditionally been taken to be α participle formed from ἀ + τρυγάω, unharvested or barren, but Beekes says this is "formally not easy" and discusses a couple of other possibilities. What is it that doesn't work about this etymology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If from τρυγάω, the expected form would be ἀτρύγητος, since in such formations the stem vowel is lengthened (and long α becomes η in Ionic). Chantraine tentatively mentions the possibility that ἀτρύγετος might be a shortening of this expected form *metri causa*, but that would be an irregular development.

Comment: Are there any other instances of eta to episolon made *metri causa*? I can think of a few instances of quantitative metathesis, but not like this (at least nothing is coming to mind).

Comment: @cmw I can't think of any offhand.

Comment: Thanks! I put a summary it the wiktionary entry: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἀτρύγετος